# Unknown type error for Subject subscription in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a service where I have declared a subject->

`isLoading = new Subject();`

In the component, I'm trying to subscribe to the subject.

```
this.loadSubscription = this.service.isLoading.subscribe(loading=> {
        this.isLoading = loading.status;
    });
```

I'm getting a typescript type error on the loading variable. It says

***Property 'status' does not exist on type 'unknown'(loading)***.

I'm not able to add the type as any for loading variable also. How can I resolve this?

Comment: try with `public isLoading = new Subject();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `public isLoading = new Subject<any>();`
and make sure subject is imported properly from rxjs.
`import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs'`;

Answer (score 1):

`Subject` accepts generic variables. So it's more accurate to treat it as `Subject<T>`.

If you have imported `Subject` from its correct path, that is `rxjs` (and not `rxjs/dist/types` for example) `T` will default to `any`.

To properly fix your error re-check the import path and annotate `isLoading` or the `Subject`.

So if you have the type `type LoadingStatus = { status: string }` you can

1. `isLoading: Subject<LoadingStatus> = new Subject();`
2. `isLoading = new Subject<LoadingStatus>();`